# To use robotium my device must be rooted device?

Tags: android, robotium

I am learning Robotium, To automate the android using robotium my device must be rooted device?

Thanks
Chandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Not Necessary. you use Android Emulator instead of real device.

Download Android SDK and integerate with Eclipse.

**Follow this Tutor for reference** : http://code.google.com/p/robotium/source/browse/wiki/RobotiumTutorials.wiki?r=162

Comment: Thanks for the info that is not needed to be rooted.